# How to make an xml tree with tagged data in python

Tags: python, xml

I am figuring out the way how I can convert my data in tags to XML file.
example:-

```
<DEG>degree_name1</DEG> <STR>degree_stream</STR> <COLL>college studied </COLL> , <LOC>location of college</LOC> <LOC>Chennai</LOC> <YEAR>2014</YEAR> <PER>60</PER> <12TH>12th</12TH> <COLL>Higher Secondary School</COLL> , <LOC>Thirupur</LOC> State board Mar <YEAR>2011</YEAR> <PER>78.58</PER> <10TH>10th</10TH> <COLL>Chinna Samy Ammal Higher Sec</COLL>. School , <LOC>Thirupur</LOC> State board Mar <YEAR>2009</YEAR> <PER>85.6</PER>
```

Is there any good pythons library from which I can format this in the nested format like below:-

```
degree1
   degree1 stream
   degree1 college
   degree1 location
   degree1 percentage
   degree1 year
degree2
   degree2 stream
   degree2 college
   degree2 location
   degree2 percentage
   degree2 year
```

Comment: lxml library for python. You can iteratively access the parent and child nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend `lxml`. It is easy to use, results in readable code, and has a first-class tutorial: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html .